# Spivak "min" notation confusion

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits, optimization, terminology

Spivak uses a notation:

min$(1, \frac{\epsilon}{2|a| + 1})$

What does he mean by this notation? especially by "min"??

Answer (score 2):

Spivak already introduced the $\min$ and $\max$ functions in exercise 13 in the very first chapter, where he asked the reader to prove that: $$\min(a,b)=\dfrac{a+b-|a-b|}2\quad\color{grey}{\text{and}}\quad\max(a,b)=\dfrac{a+b+|a-b|}2.\tag1$$
What the $\min$ function basically does, is it outputs the smallest number from the input. So $\min(a,b)=a$ if $a\leqslant b$ and $\min(a,b)=b$ if $b\leqslant a$. The $\max$ function does the opposite.

I have written a hand-wavy explanation showing the intuition behind the formulas in $(1)$ [here](https://brilliant.org/discussions/thread/the-max-and-min-functions-what-are-they-a-response/?ref_id=274421).

Comment: thanks; out of curiosity, how can you **prove** that min(a, b) idea?

Comment: @Amad27 The formula easily follows by using the definition of the absolute value and trying two cases: $a\lt b$ and $b\lt a$. For the intuitive side, see the link I referenced after my recent edit.

Comment: out of curiosity (again), do you have a copy of Spivak? In page 95 of the limits, the proof is a bit weird. He states if $|x - a| < min(1, \epsilon/(2|a| + 1))$ then $|x^2 - a^2| < \epsilon$ The goal is to prove as $x ->a, x^2 -> a^2$

Comment: @Amad27 Yes, okay I will try to guide you so that you can prove it: $$|x-a|\lt\min\left(1,\dfrac{\varepsilon}{2|a|+1}\right)\Longrightarrow |x-a|\lt 1\quad\text{and}\quad|x-a|\lt\dfrac{\varepsilon}{2|a|+1}.$$

Comment: thanks. I notice an issue though. If the minimum is $1$ then there is an issue; $\epsilon < 1$ but then we dont know if $|x - a| < \epsilon$ how does this work then?

Comment: @Amad27 As Spivak said for small enough $\varepsilon$ we have: $$\min\left(1,\dfrac{\varepsilon}{2|a|+1}\right)=\dfrac{\varepsilon}{2|a|+1}.$$

Comment: Okay, that proves $|x - a| < \epsilon$, how will it prove $|x^2 - a^2| < \epsilon$?

Comment: Okay, that proves $|x - a| < \epsilon$, how will it prove $|x^2 - a^2| < \epsilon$?

Comment: @Amad27 To prove that $$|x-a|\lt\min\left(1,\dfrac{\varepsilon}{2|a|+1}\right)\Longrightarrow |x^2-a^2|\lt\varepsilon,$$ you need to use the following lemma: *If $|x-x_0|\lt\min\left(1,\dfrac{\varepsilon}{2(|y_0|+1)}\right)$ and $|y-y_0|\lt\min\left(1,\dfrac{\varepsilon}{2(|x_0|+1)}\right)$, then* $$|xy-x_0y_0|\lt\varepsilon.$$ Where you put $x_0=y_0=a$ and $y=x$. You also need to note that $$\dfrac1{2|a|+1}\gt\dfrac1{2(|a|+1)}.$$

Comment: Very nice , I am trying to devise a proof. How will you prove that $\frac{1}{2|a|+1} > \frac{1/2(|a|+1)}$ ?

Comment: @Amad27 It is trivial to note that $2(|a|+1)=2|a|+2\gt 2|a|+1$, thus $$\dfrac1{2|a|+1}\gt\dfrac1{2(|a|+1)}.$$

Comment: @Hakim: Since $min(a,a)=a$ is valid you should replace $a<b$ with $a\leq b$ and also $b<a$ with $b \leq a$. Regards,

Comment: Thanks @MarkusScheuer, I wanted when writing those statements to mention the case when $a=b$ separately but I thought it was too trivial anyway.

Comment: @Hakim: You're welcome and I see your point. Nevertheless, since we have a broad spectrum of users on MSE this rigidity may simply support the less experienced. :-)

Comment: @Hakim, thanks. But why prove the "min"? ? Why not directly prove $|x - a| < \epsilon/(2|a| +1)$ the main point is why is the "min" required? Why can you directly prove $|x - a| < \epsilon/(2|a| +1)$ instead of $min(1, |x - a| < \epsilon/(2|a| +1)$?? Thanks!

Comment: @Amad27 Because as Spivak said you need $|x-a|\lt1$ as well as $|x-a|\lt\dfrac{\varepsilon}{2|a|+1}$, which can be written using the $\min$ function as: $$|x-a|\lt\min\left(1,\dfrac{\varepsilon}{2|a|+1}\right).$$

Comment: @Hakim, that is **Exactly** my point. **why** do you need the $min$ to be there, and why do he randomly choose $1$ as one of the constants of the min function? There is no need for min, if the goal is to prove $|x - a| < \epsilon/(2|a| + 1)$

Comment: Any idea @Hakim please?

Comment: @Amad27 I'll answer you later on this night, I'm going to work now. If it is important for you to have the answer as soon as possible you may perhaps try to write another question explaining your issues. See you later.

Comment: Thank you @Hakim, Ill wait here for your response! I appreciate it =)

Comment: @Amad27 Basically we choose $|x-a|\lt1$ but we could replace $1$ by any other positive number, this will ensure that $x$ is not too large and consequently that $|x-a|$ isn't too large. And thus we need $|x-a|\lt\text{some positive number}$ as well as $|x-a|\lt\dfrac{\varepsilon}{2|a|+1}$. This conditions can be framed in terms of the $\min$ function as: $$|x-a|\lt\min\left(\text{some positive number},\dfrac{\varepsilon}{2|a|+1}\right).$$

Comment: @Hakim, but the min function chooses **ONE** Number so if $|x - a| < min(b, c)$ and $b < c$ then $|x - a| < b$ not $|x - a| < b$ **AND** $|x - a| < c$

Comment: @Amad27 Using your very own example, if $|x-a|\lt\min(b,c)$ with $b\lt c$ then as you said we have $|x-a|\lt b$ but we also have $|x-a|\lt b\lt c\Rightarrow |x-a|\lt c$ since $b\lt c$. And therefore $$|x-a|\lt\min(a,b)\iff|x-a|\lt a\quad\color{grey}{\text{and}}\quad|x-a|\lt b.$$

Comment: @Hakim, one more question. **why** do we need $|x - a|$ to be less than two numbers?

Comment: @Amad27 Spivak already gave the reasons, please re-read that chapter.

Comment: @Hakim, sorry for being a noob. If you could perhaps refer me to a place where this "min" function idea is introduced properly?

Comment: @Amad27 Did you read the article I referenced in my answer?

Comment: @Hakim wow. Sorry, my eye didnt catch that you sent an article. I'll read and reply later =)

Comment: @Hakim, why does Spivak randomly choose "1" as part of the min function? Why not 2 or 3 or some other number ??

Comment: @Amad27 Quoting Spivak: *"..., to begin with, let us require that $|x-a|\lt1$ (any positive number other than $1$ would do just as well);"*.

Comment: @Hakim but you have to prove it for all real numbers? Not just $|x - a| < 1$ Why are you assuming $|x - a| < 1$ what about for $|x - a| > 1$??? Thanks!

Comment: @Amad27 The goal when using that restriction is to **bound** the number $|x-a|$ so that it doesn't become too large, that's the basic idea behind it. We don't use $|x-a|\gt1$ because that wont lead to any bound.

Comment: @Hakim, thanks. What if $1 < \epsilon/(2|a| + 1)$ then how would this work out?

Comment: @Amad27 Re-read p92-p93, Spivak has a discussion related to your point.

Comment: @Hakim, will you mind making a chat room with me? I don't know how to. I want to discuss an issue, maybe you could help :)

Comment: @Amad27 Right, I will guide you but I'm going to work now. Later.

Answer (score 1):

He means the minimum of the two numbers.  If $\frac{\epsilon}{2|a| + 1}$ is less than $1$, then it will be that number.  Essentially, the reason for the $1$ is that he's saying the number is no greater than $1$ (if $\frac{\epsilon}{2|a| + 1}$ happens to be greater than $1$, then $1$ will be the value).

Note that the definition of how to compute the minimum isn't really important.  He's just emphasizing that the number is less than or equal to $1$.